# images are not changing after given time in java Script

Tags: javascript, css, html, image

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Slider</title>
      <style>
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <img id="text" alt="picture" src="cod4.jpg" style="width:900px;height:500px;">

      <script>
        var images = [];
        images[0]= "cod2.jpg";
        images[1]= "cod3.jpg";
        images[2]= "cod4.jpg";

        setInterval(changeimage,3000)

        function changeimage(){

        for(var i=0; i<=images.length; i++)
        {
          document.getElementById("text").src += images[i] ;
        }
      }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Images are not changing after given time in java Script.
**I am trying to change image after 3 sec but its not working.**

**Please help me whats wrong with this code ? Thanks**

Comment: Why not just have `var images=["cod2.jpg","cod3.jpg","cod4.jpg"];`? Also your for loop is overwriting the image element's src `text` so it will show the last image in the loop. Correction, it won't show the last image in the loop as you're adding to the src, not overwriting it. Thank you Artem for pointing that out. I missed the `+=`

Comment: change `document.getElementById("text").src += images[i];` to `document.getElementById("text").src = images[i];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Artem Baranovskii has posted a great answer. I'm not sure if you want the images to continuously loop so I will post this as my answer.

```js
var images=["http://placehold.it/150x150","http://placehold.it/170x170","http://placehold.it/190x190"];
var i=0;
//Set image and interval when the page has loaded (Is ready). 
window.onload=function(){
//Call changeimage to set the first image.
changeimage();
//Set interval
setInterval(changeimage,3000);
}
function changeimage(){
//Check if i is equal  to or "||" greater than array length.
if(i==images.length||i>images.length){
//If true, reset i to 0. Back to the first image in the array
 i=0;
}
//Set the image url.
document.getElementById('text').src=images[i];
//Add 1 to i. 
i++;
}
```

```html
<img id="text" src=""/>
```

> Comments in the source code but if you have any questions please leave a comment below and I will answer as soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

> Full source code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Slider</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var images=["http://placehold.it/150x150","http://placehold.it/170x170","http://placehold.it/190x190"];
var i=0;
window.onload=function(){
changeimage();
setInterval(changeimage,3000);
}
function changeimage(){
if(i==images.length||i>images.length){
    i=0;
}
document.getElementById('text').src=images[i];
i++;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="text" src=""/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the snippet works then it will work on your page too. I will show the full source code under the snippet.

Comment: @RAOHAMMAS That should work for you now. All you need to do is replace the images array to `var images=["cod2.jpg","cod3.jpg","cod4.jpg"];` If you don't understand any of the source code above, please just ask and I will explain in as much detail as possible. It's always better to understand the source code you're using rather than just copy/paste and hope for the best.

Comment: Thanks brother.....working well....but i am not understanding one thing We are not using loop  but still its working like loop...how ??? and can i skip or change window.onload to this .....<body onload="changeimage()"> ??

Comment: Yes you can remove the `window.onload` but that will trigger the interval when the page is ready. using `onload="changeimage();setInterval(changeimage,3000);"` will do the same thing but I think it look much cleaner sitting in it's own function attached to the onload event listener but it's up to you. How this works is, `var i` is set to 0 and the first image in the array is `images[0]`, `i` is replacing the 0. The interval is calling the function every 3 seconds and each time it does we  add 1 to `i`. It also checks if `i` is equal to or greater than the array, if it is it will reset.

Comment: The array contains 3 values so it's saying: does `i = 3` **OR** is `i` greater than 3? If so then set `i` back to 0. If that if condition doesn't return true then it will ignore as it doesn't have or need an else condition.

Comment: @RAOHAMMAS You are very welcome. It's nice to see some people like to understand the source code rather than just copy/pasting it. Those who ask and understand the source code might find they will use parts of existing functions in other projects. Have a great day and I wish you the vest best with your development.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
var images = ["cod2.jpg", "cod3.jpg", "cod4.jpg"],
    timer;

function changeimage() {
  var nextImage = images.shift();
  if (!nextImage) {
     clearInterval(timer);
     return;
  }

  document.getElementById("text").src = nextImage; 
}

timer = setInterval(changeimage, 3000)
```

**EDIT** Changes according to your code:

```
<!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Slider</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <img id="text" alt="picture" src="cod4.jpg" style="width:900px;height:500px;" />

       <script>
         var images = [], timer;

         images.push("cod2.jpg");
         images.push("cod3.jpg");
         images.push("cod4.jpg");

         function changeimage(){

           var nextImage = images.shift();
           if (!nextImage) {
              clearInterval(timer);
              return;
           }

           document.getElementById("text").src = nextImage; 
         }

         timer = setInterval(changeimage, 3000)
       </script>    
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks your code is working well...but please can you correct my code ??

Comment: @RAOHAMMAS if this post answers your question, marking it as the answer is a good way to show appreciation.

Comment: @RAOHAMMAS Not a problem and Welcome to Stackoverflow!